# Pretty Url on MacOS localhost doesn't work

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've made localhost on MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

Everything works great except Pretty Urls.

http://localhost/blog/ shows me the website OK.
After click on http://localhost/blog/contact/ it will show me contact page without everything else (css, javascript, index's header & footer). It looks like I've opened http://localhost/blog/contact.php

[image]

I've tried to add to index.php and contact.php:

```
echo $_GET['page'];
```

but nothing happends. Empty value.

My **.htaccess** contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/?+%]*)?$  index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have spent a lot of hours to find the right solutions but nothing works for me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you put your layout to see how are you printing the urls for css and js?

Comment: It's "http://localhost/blog/js/script.js", the same with css. Take a look on the source code screenshot I've updated.

Comment: I don't see the JS/CSS URL's in your screenshot. Also first element in HTML is red; hinting there is something wrong in your HTML? maybe an unclosed HTML tag?

Comment: Could you add an image of your devtools in the `Network` tab to see if the `css`/`js` are missing?

Comment: Guys, the Css / Js is not important. The problem is, why the .htaccess doesn't redirecting me and is ignored by Apache. I know that the screenshot doesn't show URL's. After click on http://localhost/blog/contact/ there is nothing else in source code except you can see on screenshot. There is NOT anything wrong with my Html, Css or JavaScript. There is just problem of not included contact file to index.

Comment: Make sure the rewrite module is on in apache

Comment: Also, you should be working with a custom virtual host, not with the default localhost. Because you are trying to use a composed URL as the hostname: "localhost/blog". And that will cause conflicts with things like $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. So, define a virtualhost like blog.local and you may see your problem is gone.

Comment: @mayid it sounds like it could help me to solve the problem. Could you please explain it more? Should I create file blog.local to <pre>Users/username/Sites/</pre> or <pre>Users/username/Sites/blog/</pre>? What should the file contains? I have never heard about this before.  Thank you.

Comment: The rewrite module is ON.

Comment: Sure, apart from mapping host names to ips you need to configure virtualhosts in apache for each project. Is this your first time with apache? Follow a tutorial. There're thousands. IE: https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-macos-sierra-10-12-bca5a5dfffba#.4vv6xbr9k See Configuring Apache section.

Comment: @mayid thank you, but it doesn't work. I've tried to set virtual host but no change. No, it's not my first time with Apache. I've been doing it still the way like index.php?page=contact for example. Then on FTP I set the .htaccess. Now it's the time to get it works on localhost but I don't understand why it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Well, don't get confused about this. One thing are friendly urls like the one you mentioned. So, with .htaccess rules you convert index.php?page=contact to /contact. But we were talking about something else, something that you must take care in your localhost, that is creating virtualhosts.

Comment: Think about this: when you pay for hosting a web, normally your web page shares the same machine (and resources) with other pages. Your host differentiates each with a hostname, like mypage.com, and the same thing should happen in your own pc with your projects. You must assign hostnames for them. Like mypage.local or mypage.dev or even mypage.com if yo want. All of them will be aliases for 127.0.0.1 just like localhost is.

Comment: So, localhost is just your first virtualhost. Now you need to create new virtualhosts, one for each project. And each one of them will be mapped to a folder and make that folder the root of the project. Starting from http://localhost/blog/ you need to get to http://blog.local, otherwise you will have trouble with your root folder, because your files are located (i guess) under www/blog (or httpd/blog) an localhost points to just www.

Comment: So a .htaccess rule to get to http://localhost/blog/contact will mess things up until you define your virtualhost root to www/blog and the name to something like http://blog.local. Hope you'll get this working soon. You just have to get familiar with the concept of a virtual host and set it up.